# como saber si el resultado de una búsqueda de mysql es undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql

necesito saber si mi atributo "iteraccion" a un no tiene valor en mi base de datos
si aun no lo tiene, tengo que agregarle el valor

este es mi codigo

```
objBD.query('SELECT u.ID_U, u.nombre, t.ID_T,t.tiempo,t.iteracion from USUARIO u  INNER JOIN TIEMPOS t ON u.ID_U=t.ID_U where u.nombre=?',[usuarioNombre], function(err, rows, fields) {
        if((rows[0].iteracion=="undefined")){   
        (rows[0].iteracion)
        }
```

en el condicional tengo dudas

> if((rows[0].iteracion=="undefined")){

Comment: Prueba con `if((typeof rows[0].iteracion == "undefined"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias hacer lo siguiente

```
if(err) {
    return console.log('Error1');
} else if (rows.length) {                                                   
    return console.log('Trae datos');
} else if (rows[0].iteracion) {
    return console.log('Existe el valor');
}
```

Para comprobar basta con identificar si tiene o no un valor `truthy`, ejemplo

- null
- undefined
- NaN
- empty
- 0
- false

Aunque el link que te dejo esta en Ingles es facil de entender traduciendolo!

[Valores Truthy y Falsy](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)

Ademas, si tu estas seguro que este valor podria tener o no valores (que me imagino que es asi el caso) puedes utilizar

```
if( typeof rows[0].iteracion !== "undefined" ) {

}
```

Siguiendo la respuesta de @rnd puedo probar y deducir que la diferencia entre ocupar `"undefined"` y `undefined` es que una hace referencia a "tipo" y la otra a "valor"

Por ejemplo si yo tuviera

```
var prueba;
if(prueba === undefined){
    alert("No esta declarada");
}
```

Seria lo correcto utilizarlo sin comillas ya que es una variable que no esta definida pero si declarada. Y nos enviaria la alerta. Si yo borrara `var prueba;` no caeria en el if y la consola me mostraria el error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: prueba is not defined

Mientras que si ocupo

```
if(typeof prueba === "undefined"){
   alert("No esta declarada");
}
```

Aqui seria correcto utilizarlo con comillas ya que no existe como declarada.

En tu caso particular tu defines `rows` y si la consulta no devuelve datos SEGUN YO `rows[0].iteration` no esta declarada y deberias utilizar `"typeof rows[0].iteration undefined"`

Comment: Claro, tu sabes, esto se puede hacer de muchas formas XD. Como el no uso `typeof` no lo puse. Aqui, como el array si existe, no daria la exception, no me parecio necesario agregarlo. Muy buena respuesta por cierto. muy completa. Salu2

Comment: @rnd jajaja es que lei tu respuesta y me salto la duda xD saludos y gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Si un valor es `undefined`, basta con hacer

```
if (!rows[0].iteracion) {
   // el valor NO esta definido (notese el !)
}
```

Si quieres algo mas estricto puedes usar lo siguiente: Ten en cuenta que `undefined` es una palabra reservada y *no va entre comillas*.

```
if(rows[0].iteracion !== undefined){   
   // el valor NO esta undefined 
}
```

o

```
if(rows[0].iteracion === undefined){   
   // el valor esta undefined 
}
```

Notese, `!==` y `===`. Operadores estrictos de igualdad.

Salu2

Comment: puedes ver mi respuesta, me  quedo con la duda y probe lo que agregue!